# Mongoose store query result in variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can store the query result from an aggregate function into a variable and use it in other functions.
i have this function to count the records:

```
const utilitiesFunctions = {};
utilitiesFunctions.conteoBatch = (callback) => {
  workOrder.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$batches"
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "$batches",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }, function(err, conteos) {
    callback(conteos);
  });
}

module.exports = utilitiesFunctions;
```

the resutl is:

```
[ { _id: 591c9fc757ddf611fc7c5840, total: 2 },
  { _id: 591c9a9e5683f81b8c48e44c, total: 1 } ]
```

I use a LOOP to search for the _id with the lower count. how can pass the id to a variable to use it in other validation functions, something like this:

```
var idb = utilitiesFunctions.conteoBatch();//idb=591c9fc757ddf611fc7c5840
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need must be something like this

```
 let objWithSmallestCount = {};
 let results = utilitiesFunctions.conteoBatch();
```

let's say your algo for finding the smallest count is isSmallestCount()

```
 for (let result of results) {
     if (isSmallestCount(result.total) {
         objWithSmallestCount = result;
     }
 }
```

from this point on you can do whatever you want with it

```
 let id = objWithSmallestCount._id;
```

Comment: the variable is empty